# java method synchronization and read/write mutual exclusion

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have two methods `read()` and `write()` as below in a class.

```
class Store
{

  public void write()
  {
    // write to store;
  }

  public string  read()
  {
    // read from store;
  }
}
```

1) The `Store` object is a singleton.

2) I have a `Writer` class which will write to the store and several `Reader` classes which will read from the store at the same time.

My requirement is that when the writer is writing to the store, all the readers should wait. i.e., when control is in `write()`, all the calls to `read()` should be blocked.  How do I achieve this? I have tried `synchronize(Store.class)` in the `write()` method, but doesn't seem like work for me.

Comment: you don't want to synchronize on the class object (`synchronized (foo.class)`) but instead on the instance you are operating on.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The best option in this case is to use a reader-writer lock: [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). It allows a single writer, but multiple concurrent readers, so it's the most efficient mechanism for this type of scenario.

Some sample code:

```
class Store
{
    private ReadWriteLock rwlock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public void write()
    {
       rwlock.writeLock().lock();
       try {
          write to store;
       } finally {
          rwlock.writeLock().unlock();
       }
    }

    public String read()
    {
       rwlock.readLock().lock();
       try {
          read from store;
       } finally {
          rwlock.readLock().unlock();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: ReadWriteLock is an interface. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Sorry about that. Fixed. :)

Comment: @Tudor you should always wrap your _read to store_ and _write to store_ operations in a _try_ block and make sure to have your `unlock()` methods in a corresponding _finally_ block to prevent that the locks remain locked if an exception occurs.

Comment: @vijvij123: Don't forget to come back and accept the answer if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 6):

`synchronized` is the simplest solution so you should explain what you mean by "doesn't seem like work for me" and perhaps show us how you used it.

The better solution is to use [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) because it allows concurrent access to readers as well.

Answer (score 5):

When a method is synchronized on some object, a thread executing this method blocks all the other threads that try to enter another block/method **that is synchronized on the same object**.

So, if you want the writer threads to forbid any reader thread to read, you must synchronize both the write and the read method. There is no reason to synchronize on the `Store` class. Synchronizing on the `Store` object is more natural:

```
public synchronized void write() {
  write to store;
}

public synchronized String read() {
  read from store;
}
```

This, however, (maybe) has a drawback: it also forbids two reader threads to read at the same time. If you really need this to happen, you should use a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). But this will lead to code that is less performant, and harder to understand and maintain. I would only use it if I have measured that this is needed.

Comment: Why would you say that `ReadWriteLock` is less performant than `synchronized`? There's no good technical reason for that to be so since both methods should just be a higher-level interface to direct semaphore manipulation.

Comment: In fact it looks like `ReentrantReadWriteLock` may actually perform *better* than `synchronized`, as long as you don't use "fair" locks. That seems to be one conclusion of [this IBM comparison between `synchronized` and `ReentrantLock`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10264/). Although it's worth nothing that `ReentrantLock` is not the same as `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, why would you lock readers out if you don't have to?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that readers cannot read out the datastructure concurrently, while in many cases, this is not a problem at all...

Answer (score 0):

Use a ReadWriteLock from java.util.concurrent package

Answer (score 0):

Take care to read this article:

https://blog.takipi.com/java-8-stampedlocks-vs-readwritelocks-and-synchronized/

- RWLocks can be slow especially when there are many readers to writers
- synchronized is on average the most reliably fast
- there are new locks like StampedLock